# Specify custom `virtualenv` command for tox

Tags: python, virtualenv, tox

Is there a way to specify the location of the `virtualenv` executable for `tox` to use?

Here is the problem:

The company I work for uses its own patched python with its own `virtualenv`. That virtualenv executable is very old, and it cannot be used to install the dependencies needed for the project, so when the project is initialized and the virtual environment for that project is created, the `virtualenv` executable in that environment gets updated to a later version. When I activate that environment and try to run tox in it, tox uses that environment's virtualenv executable to create its own (that is, tox's) virtual environments. However, that updated virtualenv executable cannot create a correctly configured virtual environment for that patched python. To do that, I need to be able to call the initial 'old' patched virtualenv executable, and thus I need to be able to tell tox where to look for it.

Hope this explanation is not too convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only real option is to create a tox plugin that uses the patched virtualenv - see https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/blob/master/src/tox/venv.py#L698 and https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html#creating-a-plugin